# How to get the date and time in format 2022-10-03T19:45:47.844Z in Java

Tags: java, datetime-format, simpledateformat, iso8601, offsetdatetime

I need the current system date and time in 2022-10-03T19:45:47.844Z format in a java class.

I tried using the zoneddatetime and simple date format but couldn't get the write syntax or code from online. I'm beginner in Java, any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: `Instant.now().toString()` (yes, if you accept not having control over the number of decimals, it really is this simple). Leave out `.toString()` if you do not require a `String`.

Comment: @OleV.V. Neither [that Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56933100/642706) nor [that Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64872001/642706) is a direct original of this one. Both are convoluted, neither directly asks for today's date in ISO 8601 format, and both are Android-specific. I expected an original existing Question to mark this Question as a duplicate, but I could not find one. Thus my Answer.

Comment: Do you know for a fact that you need exactly three decimals of fraction of second (as in `.844`)? Asking because your format is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and that standard doesn’t put a limit on the number of decimals.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the current time in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:Sec.Millisecond format in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459656/how-to-get-the-current-time-in-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmisec-millisecond-format-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.now().toString()
```

See this [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/9MMZAm).

> 2022-11-08T07:18:21.482293Z

## `Instant.now().toString()`

As [commented by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74356407/how-to-get-the-date-and-time-in-format-2022-10-03t194547-844z-in-java#comment131268994_74356407), you can capture the current moment as seen with an [offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC by using the `java.time.Instant` class.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

### ISO 8601

You can generate a string in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, your desired format. by calling `Instant#toString()`.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

Of course we can combine these:

```
Instant.now().toString()
```

### Resolution

An `Instant` represents a moment in UTC with a resolution as fine as nanoseconds.

Note that [`Instant#toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#toString()) uses a [formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT) that formats the fractional seconds in groups of three digits, up to nine digits for nanoseconds. Any finer group of all zeros is suppressed. So if your `Instant` has only [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) with zero [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond)/[nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond), you get three digits. If micros without nanos, six digits. If nanos, nine digits.

You will likely capture the current moment with:

- Milliseconds (3 digits in fractional second) in Java 8.
- Microseconds (6 digits) in Java 9 and later, due to a fresh implementation of the [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html) class in the [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) project’s codebase.

Common computer hardware clocks are not accurate in nanoseconds. So a `Instant` can represent a value with nanoseconds, but you'll not likely see the current moment captured with that precision.

If you want only milliseconds, [truncate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)). Specify your desired granularity by way of [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) enum, and implementation of [`TemporalUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalUnit.html).

```
Instant.now().truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MILLIS ).toString()
```

But remember, if you happened to have a fractional second of zero, no fractional second digits at all would appear in the resulting `String` object.

### `Z`

The `Z` on the end of your desired format means an offset of zero. Pronounced “Zulu”. Comes from aviation/military history. Standardized in ISO 8601.

### Avoid legacy date-time classes

You said:

> I tried using the zoneddatetime and simple date format

The [`java.time.ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class is for representing a moment as seen in a particular time zone. Your desired format has no time zone, only an offset of zero. So `ZonedDateTime` is not appropriate here. Use `Instant` instead, or use [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) if you need more flexibility such as other formatters.

Definitions:

- An [offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) is **merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds** ahead or behind the temporal prime meridian of UTC.
- A [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) is much more. A time zone is a **named history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset** used by the people of a particular region as decided by their politicians.

Never use the terribly flawed classes of `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date`, `Calendar`, etc. These are now legacy since Java 8+, supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 1):

ZonedDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)

Comment: Not completely correct, though on the right track. Expected output: `2022-11-08T08:16:24.715Z` Observed output in my time zone: `2022-11-08T09:16:24.715128761`. The time is 1 hour off corresponding to my UTC offset, and the trailing `Z` is missing. It does not matter that there are more decimals since according to the ISO 8601 standard the number of decimals is free.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a fully specified timestamp in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. While java.util.Date and friends make this difficult, you can include [joda](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) in your classpath and use the following incantation to manipulate it:

> System.out.println(ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().print(DateTime.now());

Good luck!

Comment: The [*Joda-Time*](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode). Its successor is the *java.time* classes built into Java 8, defined by JSR 310. Both Joda-Time and JSR 310 are lead by the same man, Stephen Colebourne.